# Preseeding Ubuntu installation so it uses all the disk

Tags: debian-installer, preseed

I need to preseed a dual boot installation of Ubuntu 10.04. I want `partman` to use all already existing Linux partitions and all free space (like the option when installing Fedora) what would that recipe look like?

Comment: use `gparted` if available, it don't need no stinkin' recipies (and is very robust and intuituve)

Comment: You could leave the answer empty, which would allow you to select it during install.

Comment: No the whole idea is to make the install unattended.

Answer (score 3):

I can't remember if I fixed that, but you can take a look at my answer file:

> http://www.north-winds.org/unix/preseed/preseed-example.cfg

It's based off of a more sophisticated example at:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt

EDIT: In case the link above goes stale, here is the complete contents of the file:

```
# Locale sets language and country.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
#d-i console-setup/modelcode string pc105
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us
# To select a variant of the selected layout (if you leave this out, the
# basic form of the layout will be used):
#d-i console-setup/variantcode string dvorak

# Install the Ubuntu desktop.
tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect ubuntu-desktop
# On live DVDs, don't spend huge amounts of time removing substantial
# application packages pulled in by language packs. Given that we clearly
# have the space to include them on the DVD, they're useful and we might as
# well keep them installed.
ubiquity    ubiquity/keep-installed string icedtea6-plugin openoffice.org
ubiquity    ubiquity/summary    string
ubiquity    ubiquity/reboot boolean true

ubiquity    languagechooser/language-name   string English
ubiquity    countrychooser/shortlist    string US
ubiquity    localechooser/supported-locales string en_US.UTF-8

ubiquity    time/zone   string America/Los_Angeles

# Not needed if only one disk
#ubiquity   partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
ubiquity    partman-auto/method string regular
ubiquity    partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm string boolean true
ubiquity    partman-md/device_remove_md string boolean true
ubiquity    partman-lvm/confirm string boolean true
ubiquity    partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

ubiquity    partman/confirm_write_new_label string boolean true
ubiquity    partman/choose_partition select finish
ubiquity    partman/confirm string boolean true
ubiquity    partman/confirm_nooverwrite string boolean true

ubiquity    passwd/user-fullname string John Doe III
ubiquity    passwd/username string user
ubiquity    passwd/user-password string alamepassword
ubiquity    passwd/user-password-again string alamepassword
ubiquity    user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
```

Comment: @Anthon: and indeed this link has gone stale by now.

Comment: @Anthon Point taken. That was a link to a file on my own website, but I moved it's location slightly. I've updated the link and added the complete contents of the file as well.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Link fixed.

Comment: @penguin359: outstanding response. Let me glance over your questions and answers and spend a few more upvotes.

Comment: Could you reduce the example to the relevant parts? I'm sure that language/locale/country choosers are irrelevant here.

Comment: @Braiam Possibly, but this answer is 4 years old now. It's been quite a while since I've had to work with preseeded installs. All I know is that if a question is asked, and not preseeded, then the user will have to manually answer it during the install. The OP said he wanted the entire install unattended and language is a question that is asked during install.

Comment: Time doesn't matter. If you are not willing to maintain it, who you are expecting that is?

Comment: @Braiam Well, if my answer is no longer valid, I can always delete it, but I don't have time to try and recreate a VM and preseed an Ubuntu install to verify what is and is not needed or if any changes are required. The original poster wanted a completely automatic install with partitions being wiped. I don't know if any of those lines can be removed without breaking a completely automatic install of Ubuntu. Feel free to take over ownership if you would like to.